# how to replace record name in specific action in odoo?

Tags: python, xml, odoo

i have a model called patient contains all patient data,
i need to add another menu for some group of users that open the model but without any sesnative data such as Name, but it's by default the _rec_name of the model,
how to hide the name of the patient on specific action to be another field or static string like "Patient"

any help will be appreciated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do it by overriding the name_get method and add the new condition that will return another name if I'm using the model in my new menu which appears only for the new group

```
def name_get(self):
    result = []
    if not self.env.user.has_group('pl_analytic.group_pl_analytic'):
        for patient in self:
            name = patient.full_name
            result.append((patient.id, name))
    else:
        for patient in self:
            result.append((patient.id, patient.identification_code))
    return result
```

thanks for all

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need to split the data in to the two models or more models.
And then use Delegation inheritance. Then you can separate sensitive info and nonsensitive more easily.

Read more about that here:
https://www.odoo.com/documentation/14.0/reference/orm.html#inheritance-and-extension

You can see example here `hr.employee` has 3 models: base, public and private.

https://github.com/odoo/odoo/tree/14.0/addons/hr/models